# Display a single Drupal page as https

Tags: 7

I need to display one of the pages on the site as a secure page, currently it's:
http://www.mypage.co.uk

and it needs to be:
https://sub.mypage.co.uk/

I can add a redirect to htaccess but the page doesn't show the styling as it's not https.

Also the certificate that the client has bought only covers this page.

I tried using secure pages but I get a Forbidden error when I try to view the page.

What do I need to do to display a single page on a subdomain URL and as https?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Drupal Answers! The format for posts is pretty strict here. You should reword your post so there's an explicit question being asked.

Comment: To add what @ShawnConn said, the question should not  be on the line of _What do you suggest?_ or _Do you have any hints?_